# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search while loop through Json Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I tried my best to loop through very child of Json Object that is like below:

```
var ReportObj = {
  "ReportDict": {
    "101": {
      "ActivePortfolio": 1,
      "ApprovalAmount": "$ 0.00",
      "BranchDesc": "Home Loan",
      "DisbursedAmount": "$ 12,000.00",
      "Female": 1,
      "Male": 0,
      "NumberOfApproval": 0,
      "NumberOfDisbursed": 1,
      "PortfolioAmount": "$ 11,900.00",
      "TotalActiveClient": 1,
      "TotalMaleFemale": 1
    },
    "102": {
      "ActivePortfolio": 0,
      "ApprovalAmount": "$ 0.00",
      "BranchDesc": "Staff Home Loan",
      "DisbursedAmount": "$ 0.00",
      "Female": 0,
      "Male": 0,
      "NumberOfApproval": 0,
      "NumberOfDisbursed": 0,
      "PortfolioAmount": "$ 0.00",
      "TotalActiveClient": 0,
      "TotalMaleFemale": 0
    }
  }
```

To get each of Json child value, I used `$.each()` in jQuery like this:

```
var table = '';
$.each(ReportObj, function(index, value) {
  $.each(value, function(i, v) {
    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<td>' + v['BranchDesc'] + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + v['NumberOfApproval'] + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + v['ApprovalAmount'] + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + v['NumberOfDisbursed'] + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + v['DisbursedAmount'] + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + v['ActivePortfolio'] + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + v['PortfolioAmount'] + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + v['Male'] + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + v['Female'] + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + v['TotalActiveClient'] + '</td>';
    table += '<td></td>';
    table += '</tr>';
  })
})
$('table.reportTable tr:not(.bg-info)').remove()
$('table.reportTable').append(table);
```

Without knowing what was going wrong, I got the error message in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '3574' in
>   {"101":{"ActivePortfolio":1,"ApprovalAmount":"$
>   0.00","BranchDesc":"Home Loan","DisbursedAmount":"$ 12,000.00","Female":1,"Male":0,"NumberOfApproval":0,"NumberOfDisbursed":1,"PortfolioAmount":"$
>   11,900.00","TotalActiveClient":1,"TotalMaleFemale":1},"102":

The solutions I have found

- [github.com:Import optional dependency?](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1385)
- [sitepoint.com:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use ‘in’ operator to search for ‘length’](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-length/259169)
- [youtube:Jquery problem (loop td $.each) - Uncaught TypeError Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '4' in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oc5w0M7k608)

However, none of above solved my problem.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes it is correct, i did not know that my JSON `ReportObj` is already a string or not. First assumption, they was the string since they were already in double quote. However, from your referral link above, I added  ```ReportObj = JSON.parse(ReportObj);``` helps solve my problem. Thanks very much  :)

Comment: @A.Wolff, I'm using jquery version `1.11.1`

Comment: @HouyNarun: No, `ReportObj` isn't a string. It's an object.